# How can I make comparison between two text values with priority line over each other, in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have two lists , both full of these 4 text values : "Mainland", "Island ", "City" and "DP". Im trying to make a function that checks the combination of 2 in each  row . But I reached a dead end, i cant think of how to do it.The priority given over eachother is : City < Mainland < Island < DP. An example would be :

[image]

Its two columns ("From" and  "To") full of "Mainland", "Island", "City" and "DP" forming random combinations like shown above. I need a way to show in the "Category" column, in each row , the word that is superior than the other following the City < Mainland < Island < DP principle . eg Island is above City so in a combination of those 2, category shows "Island".

The idea is similar to 1<2<3 and it compares combinations of two at a time and puts in the cell the  higher one

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its two columns full of "Mainland", "Island", "City" and "DP" forming rundom combinations like shown above. I need a way to show in the "Category" column, in each row , the word that is superior than the other following the City < Mainland < Island < DP principle . eg Island is above City so in a combination of those 2, category shows "Island".

Comment: Please post your sheet as formatted ascii text. And add the clarification to your Question, so it's not just here in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `D2` paste the following formula:

```
=IF(MATCH(B2,{"City","Mainland","Island","DP"},)>=MATCH(C2,{"City","Mainland","Island","DP"},),INDEX({"City","Mainland","Island","DP"},MATCH(B2,{"City","Mainland","Island","DP"},)),INDEX({"City","Mainland","Island","DP"},MATCH(C2,{"City","Mainland","Island","DP"},)))
```

Now copy the formula downward.

However, a better way to do the same is to create a list somewhere on a sheet of the values in order. For example:

`Z1` = City

`Z2` = Mainland

`Z3` = Island

`Z4` = DP

Now, select `Z1:Z4` and use the Name Box to name that range: `Order`

Now the formula can be shortened to:

```
=IF(MATCH(B2,Order,)>=MATCH(C2,Order,),INDEX(Order,MATCH(B2,Order,)),INDEX(Order,MATCH(C2,Order,)))
```

And a cleaner way still is to use the Name Manager (Ctrl-F3) to store the list as a named formula, `Order`:

```
={"City","Mainland","Island","DP"}
```

In this way you need not clutter up a worksheet with the ordered list definition.

Comment: Hey, yeah it worked !!. AT first it didnt but i just had to make some adjustments. Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE` functions:

```
=INDEX({"City","Mainland","Island","DP"},AGGREGATE(14,0,(A2:B2={"City","Mainland","Island","DP"})*{1,2,3,4},1))
```

[image]

**Edit:**

If values are in non adjacent columns:

```
=INDEX({"City","Mainland","Island","DP"};AGGREGATE(14,0,(((B2={"City","Mainland","Island","DP"})+(F2={"City","Mainland","Island","DP"}))>0)*{1,2,3,4},1))
```

Comment: You are assuming the OP has a new version of Excel.

Comment: Also i have Office 365 and it says its a 2002  version of excel.. Always been updating though.